# convert url encoded data to JSON array or js array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

How can I convert data that looks like it is url encoded to a JSON array or js array.

```
&nfl_s_delay=120&nfl_s_stamp=1109033755&nfl_s_left1=Cleveland%2024%20%20%20Cincinnati%203%20(END%20OF%204TH)&nfl_s_right1_count=0&nfl_s_url1=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400554328&nfl_s_left2=Kansas%20City%2017%20%20%20Buffalo%2013%20(00:00%20IN%204TH)&nfl_s_right2_count=0&nfl_s_url2=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400554332&nfl_s_left3=Miami%2016%20%20%20Detroit%2020%20(00:00%20IN%204TH)&nfl_s_right3_count=0&nfl_s_url3=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400554355&nfl_s_left4=^Dallas%2031%20%20%20Jacksonville%2017%20(FINAL)&nfl_s_right4_count=0&nfl_s_url4=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400554358&nfl_s_left5=San%20Francisco%2027%20%20%20New%20Orleans%2024%20(END%20OF%201ST%20OT)&nfl_s_right5_count=0&nfl_s_url5=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400554362&nfl_s_left6=Tennessee%207%20%20%20Baltimore%2021%20(00:00%20IN%204TH)&nfl_s_right6_count=0&nfl_s_url6=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400554367&nfl_s_left7=Pittsburgh%2013%20%20%20NY%20Jets%2020%20(END%20OF%204TH)&nfl_s_right7_count=0&nfl_s_url7=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400554370&nfl_s_left8=Atlanta%2027%20%20%20Tampa%20Bay%2017%20(END%20OF%204TH)&nfl_s_right8_count=0&nfl_s_url8=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400554372&nfl_s_left9=Denver%2041%20%20%20Oakland%2010%20(00:00%20IN%203RD)&nfl_s_right9_count=0&nfl_s_url9=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400554396&nfl_s_left10=St.%20Louis%2014%20%20%20Arizona%2010%20(00:00%20IN%202ND)&nfl_s_right10_count=0&nfl_s_url10=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400554397&nfl_s_left11=NY%20Giants%2017%20%20%20Seattle%2017%20(00:00%20IN%203RD)&nfl_s_right11_count=0&nfl_s_url11=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/boxscore?gameId=400554400&nfl_s_left12=Chicago%20at%20Green%20Bay%20(8:30%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right12_count=0&nfl_s_url12=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554403&nfl_s_left13=Carolina%20at%20Philadelphia%20(8:30%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right13_count=0&nfl_s_url13=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554408&nfl_s_count=13&nfl_s_loaded=true
```

I would split split by &nfl_s_left2= , but the parameter increases by one for each time. So I could split by &nfl_s_left2= but that would only split once as the next thing that is similar is &nfl_s_left3= . So I guess a more specific question is can I split by a variable string?
I could split by &nfl_s_left but then I'd get the number= in the value of the array.

What would be the best way I could clean up this data?

Comment: Have you thought about regex?

Comment: @Knerd how can I use regex? Can you show me with an example. Wouldn't I still be splitting at a specific regex and encounter the issue where the thing I need to split by changes

Comment: check this website out, http://regex101.com/ you can click a regex like you need it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this

```
function url_split(str){
    var jsArry={},tmp = str.split('&nfl_s_'),tmp2;
    tmp.forEach(function(e){
    tmp2 = e.split('=');
        jsArry[tmp2[0]] = tmp2[1];
    });
    return jsArry;
}
```

and the fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/oswspkL0/